# Google Drive List API - not listed all the documents?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to list all the documents using Google Drive List API. But it doesn't list all the documents some documents details are not presented in the response.

This issue occurred in some of our customer's Drive account. When tried in OAuth2 playground, it results in the same response with missing documents list for these users.

Note : scope I used https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

File mimetype is "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"

Can anyone please help me to find out the reason for this ?

Comment: can you post some of your code ?

Comment: Not only in my code. I tried in OAuth2 playground there also same response only came ( some files are listed )

Comment: eithe they are trashed or maybe there is a problem with the mimetype.

Comment: No that files are not trashed. I have cross verified.

Comment: And its not that they are in a diffrent directory?

Comment: Those files are not in different directory. All files are located in  My Drive .

Comment: Directory is irrelevant when listing all files

Comment: Are you following ALL the next page tokens even if the page is empty? I bet thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the resultlist is limited to 100 items. You might want to check that!
There's an option to increase this limit:

```
            DocumentsListQuery dlq = new DocumentsListQuery(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri) 
            { 
                NumberToRetrieve = 100000,
                ShowFolders = true,
                Trashed = false
            };
```